# Finding stellar radii

Tags: luminosity, apparent-magnitude, radius

Is apparent magnitude of star, distance(in pc) and effective temperature enough to calculate its stellar radii or we need some extra information?

Comment: You’ll also need its spectral type, at the very least.

Comment: You don't need any additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a [bolometric correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometric_correction) from the effective temperature (this is reasonably insensitive to gravity and metallicity, which you don't know). Then convert the apparent magnitude into a bolometric magnitude and then into a flux. Then, I suppose you have to assume there is no extinction to estimate the intrinsic luminosity of the star by multiplying by $4\pi d^2$.

From there you can approximate the star as a blackbody and use Stefan's law, your intrinsic luminosity and the given temperature to estimate a radius.

So to answer your question directly: no. You need to know the extinction and, to get an accurate estimate, you would need to know the type of star, its chemical composition and use a better model than a blackbody for its spectrum.

Comment: We can just use distance modulus formula if an approximation is  required I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Yes

1. Convert Apparent magnitude into absolute magnitude using distance modulus.
   2.Then use stefan law and Flux Luminosity relationship.